# How to select a variable plus some other fields in Linq to object?

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the following linq query:

```
from r in result
join oUS in onOrderUS on r.ItemGUID equals oUS.ItemGUID into jOnOrderUS
from oUS in jOnOrderUS.DefaultIfEmpty()
let OnOrderUS = oUS != null ? oUS.UnitQty : 0
select (new Func<ItemMinMaxView>(() =>
{
   r.OnOrderUS = OnOrderUS;

   return r;
})).Invoke()
```

I want to select r from result, but fill a field with the data from oUS.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too would like to see the query split into more logical parts to aid readability. But I would then take advantage of the [Reactive Extensions (Rx)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/threads) to cause the side effect you want (ie the value assignment).

First up I would just create the query like Anthony suggested, but I want to check that your query is correct.

If there are more than one `onOrderUS` records returned then you'll only assign the last one found to the `ItemMinMaxView` record.

If there will only ever be zero or one record then your query is fine, but it could be simpler.

Either way, try this query instead:

```
var query =
    from r in result
    join oUS in onOrderUS on r.ItemGUID equals oUS.ItemGUID into goUSs
    let OnOrderUS = goUSs.Sum(x => x.UnitQty)
    select new
    {
        Result = r,
        OnOrderUS
    };
```

Then I'd get the final results (with the assignment side effect) like this:

```
var output = query
    .Do(x => x.Result.OnOrderUS = x.OnOrderUS)
    .Select(x => x.Result)
    .ToArray();
```

The `.Do(...)` method is part of Rx and is explicitly there for these kinds of side effects.

You do get a load of good extension methods for `IEnumerable<T>` in Rx so if you haven't checked it out you should. It's even recently been promoted to a [supported Microsoft developer tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609).

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather see your functionality split into its constituent parts. The initial query (join, projection, etc.), the mutation, and then return the specific results you need. Such as

```
var query = from r in result 
            join oUS in onOrderUS on r.ItemGUID equals oUS.ItemGUID into jOnOrderUS 
            from oUS in jOnOrderUS.DefaultIfEmpty() 
            let OnOrderUS = oUS != null ? oUS.UnitQty : 0 
            select new { r, OnOrderUS };

foreach (var item in query)
{
    item.r.OnOrderUS = item.OnOrderUS;
}

return query.Select(item => item.r);
// assumes this is in a method returning IEnumerable<R>
```

If you do not want to code the foreach, you could write it like this. I don't like mutations from queries, but this will do what you want

```
Func<R, int, R> mutateR = (r, onOrderUS) => { r.OnOrderUS = onOrderUS; return r; };

var query = from r in result 
            join oUS in onOrderUS on r.ItemGUID equals oUS.ItemGUID into jOnOrderUS 
            from oUS in jOnOrderUS.DefaultIfEmpty() 
            let OnOrderUS = oUS != null ? oUS.UnitQty : 0 
            select mutateR(r, OnOrderUS);
```

Comment: This is a little bit less effective no?  The foreach loop completely through the data.  The Func inside the select do this on the fly when the data is selected.

Comment: @EtienneT, I just don't like seeing mutations in projections. But I've provided an edit to do what you want without the foreach.

Comment: this is pretty much the same thing as declaring the Func inline the query and invoking it.  Thanks for your answer!